# How to finalize log file just after time is over when using logback SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP?

Tags: logback, appender

My object is size(10M) and time(daily) based compressed(zip) archiving, so i write the config like this:

```
<appender name="Behavior"  class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <Encoding>UTF-8</Encoding>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <FileNamePattern>${LOG_HOME}/%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.zip</FileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize> 
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %logger{50} - %msg%n
        </pattern>
   </layout>
</appender>
```

But i meet a problem. For example, today is Aug 10th, so logback is writing the log file "2013-08-10.0.log".

But the log file won't be finalized(it means be closed and compressed to "2013-08-10.0.log.zip") at Aug 11st 0:00:00. In fact, it won't be finalized until the first record after Aug 10th is written.

This means, after Aug 10th, if the first record is written at Aug 11st 16:00:00, I can't get "2013-08-10.0.log.zip" when i scan the directory between Aug 11st 0:00:00 and 16:00:00. I can only get "2013-08-10.0.log" and i can't make sure if it is finished.

How can i do to finalize the log file as soon as time is over?

Answer (score 2):

According to the logback-manual, the rollover is triggered on the first log-event AFTER the rollover time, not the time itself:

"For various technical reasons, rollovers are not clock-driven but depend on the arrival of logging events. For example, on 8th of March 2002, assuming the fileNamePattern is set to yyyy-MM-dd (daily rollover), the arrival of the first event after midnight will trigger a rollover. If there are no logging events during, say 23 minutes and 47 seconds after midnight, then rollover will actually occur at 00:23'47 AM on March 9th and not at 0:00 AM. Thus, depending on the arrival rate of events, rollovers might be triggered with some latency." (http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html)

So there is no configuration-only way to achieve what you intend. If it's this much an issue, you could perhaps try to implement code in your application that sends a logging-event right after midnight to make sure the rollover is triggered in a timely fashion. If you have no access to the main application's code, you could implement a simple little application that just clocks and only sends that one logging-event after midnight every day and uses the same appender.